# Tool that will do a circular blur/convolution

Tags: gimp, blur

I'm primarily a gimp user, but I want something to blur an image similarly to the way a lens would blur an out of focus background. AFAIK this is essentially a circular blur/convolution (assuming circular aperture and ignoring diffraction).

The operation is very straight forward, but I've been searching for a while and the only thing I can come up with is [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/#disk):

```
convert image.png -define convolve:scale=! -morphology Convolve Disk:20 blurred-image.png
```

This is great for automating tasks, but is rather cumbersome with trial and error edits. I'd also like an alternative just to double check results. *Does anyone know of a tool that does circular blur?*

<sub>If someone with rep could add more tags, please do: **convolution**, **depth-of-field**</sub>

[*EDIT*]
An example...

[image: original] [image: gamma]

[image: circular blur] [image: undo gamma, final]

[image: standard gaussian blur]

Custom convolutions give quite a small matrix (for example nothing close to 30x30) and I can't be bothered typing in weights. I'm also very much a fan of live previews with easy adjustments.

Comment: any tool capable of making a custom convolution, so Photoshop, Gimp, After effects, fusion, nuke, shake, matlab, mathematica etc.

Comment: FYI blurred backgrounds in photos are related to depth of field: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_of_field They are not literally blurring in a circular manner (though that's a common way to try and fake it, which can work to varying degrees depending on the photo being used)

Comment: @DA01 how do we lnow he does not have a  depth channel? Or indeed that he isnt painting one. Biggest problem with good bokkeh is lack of hdr data for the blur to blow intense parts right.

Comment: @joojaa I'm not sure I follow. I don't now that the OP is asking about bokkeh per se--but regardless, the effect is still done the same way via the camera--narrowing the depth of field.

Comment: @DA01 imagine that the entire picture is distant.

Comment: @joojaa Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.

Comment: In my case, I'm considering everything in the image to be at infinity and its acceptable to blur the lot. Very good point about HDR, @joojaa. I guess I could apply a temporary gamma before the blur and undo it after, though it'd lose a lot of precision.

Comment: gamma would atleast do the correct calculati. can you temporarily make the image 16 integer or even 32 bit float thatway your loss would be minimal. Anyway i would boost the sky even more. This is pretty trivial to program a plugin for. Personally id just use mathematica and manipulate its free for raspberry pi but costs a lot on real computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Focus Blur GIMP plug-in](http://registry.gimp.org/node/1444) does exactly this:

[image: Screenshot of GIMP Focus Blur plug-in]

If you're using Debian / Ubuntu Linux, you can get this and a whole bunch of other useful GIMP plugins (including the totally awesome [Resynthesizer](http://www.logarithmic.net/pfh/resynthesizer)) by installing the [gimp-plugin-registry](https://packages.debian.org/sid/gimp-plugin-registry) package.

Comment: Exactly what I'm after, thanks! If only `gimp-plugin-registry` was available for fedora so I wouldn't have to compile/install everything individually.

Comment: @jozxyqk: You could always try installing it with [alien](http://joeyh.name/code/alien/). Mind you, I've never tried that, so use it at your own risk. It might work, or it might not.

Answer (score 2):

Quite a versatile tool to generate a circular blur comes from the [GREY's Magic for Image Computing (G'MIC)](http://registry.gimp.org/node/13469) plugin for Gimp.

After installation we have access to this tool through *G'MIC > Degradations > Blur [depth-of-field]* with many convenient settings to control the blur effect:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great plugin! Thanks for pointing it out, though I haven't found a circular blur yet.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Takkat's answer, there is an even more robust and versatile tool from [GREY's Magic for Image Computing (G'MIC)](https://gmic.eu/): it is called [Blur by Color](https://gmic.eu/tutorial/blur-by-color-filter.shtml), and not only includes the capability to do a standard gradiented depth of field blur (see the first example on the Blur by Color page), but also will let you do circular blurs, motion blurs and any shaped combination of the above, using a depth/color-direction map.

Screenshot from the Blur by Color page: example 1.

[image: screenshot from the Blur by Color page]

Comment: Please do not only link to a web page, explain in your own words how one can solve the given issue with this software ... As it stands now this is a link-only-answer ...

Comment: @Kurt: This is far from a link-only answer. It is still useful with all the links removed. Please see [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/255554).